# Serial communication between python script and Arduino: Arduino not receiving message but is able to send

Tags: python, pyserial, arduino-c++

I have been working on a device that is using a python script to send and recieve a message for Arduino Nano. I have been able to send a message from the Arduino and recieve it in Python, but I am unable to send a message from Python to the Arduino.

For Python I am using the pySerial library for all the commincation. And I am writing the Arduino code in the Arduino IDE.

Here is the Python code that I am currently using:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import time

#gets the port that the arduino is using and returns it to Main function as a string
def getPort():
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    connected = []
    for element in ports:
        connected.append(element.device)
    print("Connected COM ports: " + str(connected))
    if len(connected) == 0:
        print("No Port Available")
        return 0.0
    return connected



def establishConnection(ser):
    try:
        if not ser.is_open:
            ser.open()
            print("port open")
        while True:
            
            print("PythonMSG: Transmitting")
            message = 'TX \n'
            response = ""
            message = message.encode(encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'strict')

            ser.write(b'TX \n')  # Send the message to Arduino
            #time.sleep(1)  # Give Arduino time to process the message
            response = ser.readline().decode()
            
            

            if response != "":
                if response == 'TX Failed':
                    #error that occurs sometimes is solved by restarting device
                    print("No transmission recieved, try restarting device")

                else:
                    print(f"ArduinoMSG: {response}")
                break


    ##ERROR EXCEPTIONS
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        if 'PermissionError' in str(e):
            print("Ensure you have the necessary permissions to access the COM port.")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Commincation interupt")
        if ser.is_open():
            ser.close()
    finally:
        if ser.is_open:
            ser.close()



#Sets up the port then returns it to establishConnection(ser) to attempt to commincate with arduino
def serialComm_Main(port):
    #Connect to port
    buadrate = (9600)
    port = port
    bytesize = 8
    ser = serial.Serial(port, buadrate, bytesize, timeout=5, dsrdtr=True)
    #establish serial commincation between python and device
    establishConnection(ser)
    

def Main():
    port = getPort()
    port = port[0]
    if port == 0.0:
        print("error")
    else:
         serialComm_Main(port)

Main()
```

Here is the Arduino code I am using:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  // Read the message from Python
    command.trim();  // Remove leading/trailing whitespace
    String msg = command;
    if (msg != ""){
        if (msg == "TX"){
          Serial.println("RX");
          delay(300);
        }
        else if (msg == "TX \n"){
          Serial.println("RX \n");
          delay(300);
        }
    }
    else{
      establishContactFAIL();
    }
  }
}

void establishContactFAIL(){
  while (Serial.available() <= 0){
    Serial.println("TX Failed");
    delay(300);
  }
}
```

In the python I am just printing the lines in the terminal to view the connection status and recieved and transmitted messages. The message I am getting is:

Connected COM ports: ['COM5']
PythonMSG: Transmitting
ArduinoMSG: TX Failed

Looking at the arduino nano while the coding it is running, I can see the TX LED blinking, by the RX LED never lights up.

Thank you!

Comment: try adding a sleep after you initialize the port ... it takes some time for the serial stuff to start up in arduino, at least in my experience

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the encoded `message` instead of `ser.write(b'TX \n')`?

Comment: @Kani There is no reason I chose one over the other. Either way, It did not work as intended.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have tried that as well and did not get any response. Any more suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i have used arduino to rs232/pyserial extensively ... the only issues i have run into are that it can take several seconds for the serial to initialize on the arduino board and sending data to it before its initialized can leave it in a weird state

Comment: @AustinB Have you tried with `dsrdtr=False`?